# Move focus from one control to another control just pressing enter key by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

suppose i have many html control in the page and all the control has a sequentially tab stop set.so if i press tab then focus move properly but i want to move focus just by pressing enter key instead of tab. so please tell me how could i programatically press tab when user will press enter key in my web page just by javascript or jquery. expecting small smaple code to achieve the effect i need.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(':input').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
    ti = $(this).attr('tabindex') + 1;
    $('input[tabindex='+ti+']').focus();
    //try to use________ e.which = 9; return e.which;
  }else if(e.which == 9){
    e.preventDefault(); //or return false;
  }
});
```

Javascript way:

```
<body onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){event.keyCode=9; return event.keyCode;}">
```

Comment: This is good, however the line `$('input[tabindex='+ti+']').focus();` is correct (change double quote to single) and also to prevent submit from firing need to preventDefault or return false after handling key 13. this also does not work on dropdown, the jquery selector should change