# Is it possible to move from one control to the other in an HTML form by pressing enter?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Respected All,

I have an HTML form that contains different controls like text boxes and checkboxes. I want to move focus from one control to the next when the user presses the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, without using the `tabindex` property.

Is it possible?

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP. This would be html or javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move focus from one control to another control just pressing enter key by Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683973/move-focus-from-one-control-to-another-control-just-pressing-enter-key-by-jquery)

Comment: @Pekka: The OP didn't say anything about jQuery.

Comment: @T.J. Fair enough and good answer. There doesn't seem to be an easily findable dupe without jQuery - I recommend re-wording the question title accordingly so this can become one (@saint, you okay with that?)

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Users will be used to the standard behaviour in their browser from other sites, and learning a non-intuitive behaviour just for your site will confuse both new users (when your site acts differently to their expectations) and established users (when every other site acts differently to yours). Generally you need a really good reason to do something like this successfully.

Comment: i'm new using jquery and ajax..! so i'm in learning phase... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by hooking `keypress` and looking for the Enter key, then navigating the DOM to find the next field. Vaguely like this [(live copy)](http://jsbin.com/ojoma3/2):

```
window.onload = function() {

  var form,
      index;

  // Get the form
  form = document.getElementById('theForm')

  // Hook the keypress event on all its inputs
  for (index = 0; index < form.elements.length; ++index) {
    hookEvent(form.elements[index], 'keypress', elementKeypressHandler);
  }

  // Our handler for keypresses
  function elementKeypressHandler(event) {
    var keyCode,
        next,
        tryFirst;

    // Handle IE/standards variance
    event = event || window.event;

    // Get the keycode
    keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;

    // If Enter...
    if (keyCode == 13) {
      // Find the next field; if we run out of fields, try
      // from the beginning
      tryFirst = true;
      next = this.nextSibling;
      while (next && (next.nodeType != 1 || next.tagName != "INPUT")) {
        next = next.nextSibling;
        if (!next && tryFirst) {
          tryFirst = false;
          next = this.parentNode.firstChild;
        }
      }

      // If we have one, focus it
      if (next && next !== this) {
        next.focus();
      }
    }
  }

  // Handle IE vs. standards for DOM2 event hookup
  function hookEvent(element, event, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
      element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    }
    else if (element.attachEvent) {
      element.attachEvent("on" + event, handler);
    }
    else {
      element["on" + event] = handler;
    }
    return element;
  }
};​
```

---

**Off-topic**: This stuff is a **lot** easier if you use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) to iron out browser differences for you and to make it easier to traverse the DOM. For instance, in the above, I've had to account for no fewer than *three* differences between various browsers, and I've had to use a loop to find the next (or first) element to focus, skipping over non-Element nodes. Libraries will help you avoid writing that repetitive code and focus on what you actually want to do.

Comment: waOoooOOooo That's good. its solve my lot of problems...! Infect I'm rich in my application development in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

you could instead hook into the form's submit event and just `focus()` the next input if they weren't on a submit button. less effort if you're not using a 3<sup>rd</sup> party library.