# Ignore "enter" key and move Focus after 5 characters in Text Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My client needs to scan a barcode which contains an invoice number (5 digits) and an 'enter' keystroke.

I need the input box to ignore the 'enter' key and move focus to the next input box after 5 characters.

If you could include some sample code, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type=text]').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which != 27 || e.which != 8) { // check for backspace and delete
        if (e.which != 13) { // ignoring enter
            if (!this.value.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/\d/g)) { // checking for digit
                alert('Insert Digit');
                $(this).val(''); // make the field empty
            } else {
                if (this.value.length > 4) {
                    $(this).next().focus(); // automatically change current input of length 5 digits
                }
            }
        }

    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/40/)**

Comment: This worked great. I had come up with a solution based on this [article]. However this solution was much more comprehensive and useful. [article]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683973/move-focus-from-one-control-to-another-control-just-pressing-enter-key-by-jquery

Answer (score 3):

use the onkeypress or onkeyup of the textbox and add the code if(event.keyCode==13)return false; (13 is the enter key) and the set the focus to the next control

for example you have 2 textbox   (TxtBox1 and TxtBox2)

```
 <input id="TxtBox1" type="submit" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13)return false;document.getElementById('TxtBox2').focus(); " name="Submit" value="Send" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Some JQuery:

```
$('#test').keydown(function(e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
    if ($(this).val().length == 5) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#test2').focus();
    }
}
});
```

Assume 'test' and 'test2' are the id's of the 2 text boxes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ignoring the enter key, use it as your cue to move things along. Something along the lines of:

```
$("#myTextbox").keydown(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
  // validate input and move on to the next textbox
  }
});
```